# Formulário dinâmico em html ,jquery/ajax e php

Tags: javascript

Eu não possuo muito conhecimento em js/ajax, então eu n conseguir fazer ele remover 2 elemento dinâmico, apenas um, acho q pode ser algum erro "besta" mais como n conheço a linguagem direito não estou conseguindo resolver sozinho, quando é só um campo igual o ultimo da palestra ele remove tranquilo, quando tem 2 elementos ele remove só o primeiro

```js
          $(function(){
            $("#estados").change(function(){
              var uf = $(this).val();
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "func/exibe_cidade.php?uf="+uf,
                dataType:"text",
                success: function(res){
                  $("#cidades").children(".cidades").remove();
                  $("#universidades").children(".universidades").remove();
                  $("#palestras").children(".palestras").remove();
                  $("#cidades").append(res);

                }
              });
            });
            $("#cidades").change(function(){
              var id = $(this).val();
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "func/exibe_universidade.php?id="+id,
                dataType:"text",
                success: function(res){
                  $("#universidades").children(".universidades").remove();
                  $("#palestras").children(".palestras").remove();
                  $("#universidades").append(res);

                }
              });
            });
            $("#universidades").change(function(){
              var id = $(this).val();
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "func/exibe_palestra.php?id="+id,
                dataType:"text",
                success: function(res){
                  $("#palestras").children(".palestras").remove();
                  $("#palestras").append(res);

                }
              });
            });
          });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Estado</label>  
                  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
                            <select id="estados" class="form-control" name="estados">
                            <option selected disabled>Escolha seu estado</option>
                            <?php
                              require_once "func/conn.php";
                              $sql = ('SELECT * FROM tb_estado ORDER BY nome ASC');
                              $sql = $conexao->prepare($sql);
                              $sql->execute();
                              $lista = $sql->fetchAll();
                              for ($i=0; $i < count($lista); $i++) { 

                                $uf = $lista[$i]['uf'];
                                $nome = $lista[$i]['nome'];
                            ?>

                            <option value="<?php echo $uf?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($nome)?></option>

                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div> 
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Cidade</label>  
                  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
                        <select class="form-control" name="cidades" id="cidades" required>
                          <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione o estado primeiro</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>  
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Universidade</label>  
                  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
                        <select class="form-control" name="universidades" id="universidades" required>
                          <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione a cidade primeiro</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Palestra</label>  
                  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
                        <select class="form-control" name="palestras" id="palestras" required>
                          <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione a universidade primeiro</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
```

ai no caso a parte de php esta funcionando como o que eu quero, a parte que n funciona é a de remover o campo que seria

```
    $("#universidades").children(".universidades").remove();
$("#palestras").children(".palestras").remove();
$("#universidades").append(res);
```

ele volta em php do banco de dados

```html
<?php

require_once "conn.php";

$uf = $_GET['uf'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_cidade WHERE uf = ? ORDER BY nome';
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindValue(1, $uf);
$stm->execute();
$lista = $stm->fetchAll();
for($i=0;$i<count($lista);$i++){ 
 $id = $lista[$i]['id'];
 $nome = $lista[$i]['nome'];

 echo utf8_encode('<option value="'.$id.'" class="cidades">'.$nome.'</option>');
 }
?>
```

Comment: Qual é o valor de `res`? Adicione o resultado de `console.log(res)` na pergunta

Comment: no console só aparece erro de favicon

Comment: Quais são os 2 elementos dinâmicos que vc se refere?

Comment: na vdd são 4 campos um depende do outro, estado>cidade>universidade>palestra, o codigo funciona o unico problema é quando eu mudo o estado apenas as cidades reseta, nos outros campo mantem as faculdade/palestra daquele estado, esse codigo aqui funciona pra 1 remover 1 campo só "$("#universidades").children(".universidades").remove();" se eu duplico ele e só muda o id ele n faz a função dele

Comment: No Ajax das cidades vc está enviando `uf` e nos outros `id`.

Comment: mais isso eu estou tratando no php, eu recupero a cidade pela uf, o problema é só na hora de remover, quando uso a função remove, ela só vai em 1 linha, como eu disse em cima, se eu duplico a linha ele remove somente o primeiro a 2 linha ele ignora... n entendo o por que